# Printing a kind of matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, format

I have to print this Python-code:

```
Placement     Name     Won    Played   Percent Won
1             B Borg    5       10         0.5
2             J Smith   3       6          0.5           
3
.
.
.
```

The number of players will vary, as the players are imported from a txt-file.
The top row (placement, name etc) is constant.

How can I use formatting to do this? Or if there is an easier way.
The info of the players should be aligned as is shown in the example code above.

EDIT:

```
def showLeaderboard(players): 
    print()
    print("Placement, Name, Won, Played, Percent Won")
    position = 1
    for i in players:
        print(position, end=" ")
        i.showPlayerInfo()
        position += 1

def readPlayers(): 
    fileplacement = "leads to a directory"
    if os.path.exists(fileplacement) and os.path.getsize(fileplacement) > 6:
        txtinfo = open("players.txt", "r")
        players = []
        for row in txtinfo:
            infoplayers = row.split(",")
            players.append(Spelare(infoSpelare[0], float(infoSpelare[3]), int(infoSpelare[1]), int(infoSpelare[2]))) # "players" is a class, the rest is to import from my txt-file
        return players
    else:
        print("players.txt does not seem to exist or contains unreasonables.")
        raise SystemExit(0)
```

Comment: Where is the data to be printed coming from (once you get it from the file)?  Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I've edited my post, if it is still not clear, please do ask. If I were to demonstrate all my failed attempts at this, you would instead be mad about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over your data two times. First, to see how wide each column must be, and next to actually print the data.

```
from typing import List

def prettyprint(headers: List[str], data: List[List[str]], separator: str="  ") -> None:
    # initial column width is the width of the headers
    columnwidths = [len(s) for s in headers] 
    for row in data:
        # width of the columns in this row
        cwidths = [len(s) for s in row]
        # Take the max of the previously measured columnwidths and those of this row
        columnwidths = [max(ow, cw) for ow, cw in zip(columnwidths, cwidths)]

    
    prints = [headers] + data
    for row in prints:
        # Pad the data in each cell to the correct width
        row_print = [cell.ljust(cwid) for cwid, cell in zip(columnwidths, row)]
        print(separator.join(row_print))


d =  [['1', 'B Borg', '5', '10', '0.5'], ['2', 'J Smith', '3', '6', '0.5']]
h =  ['Placement', 'Name', 'Won', 'Played', 'Percent', 'Won']
prettyprint(h, d)
```

Gives the output:

```
Placement  Name     Won  Played  Percent
1          B Borg   5    10      0.5    
2          J Smith  3    6       0.5
```

Obviously, you're going to have to modify this to work with your `Spelare` class. You can also use the functions [`rjust()` and `center()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-ljust-rjust-center/) if you want a different alignment.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you so much for the help! I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the following string methods:

- ljust
- rjust
- center

Here is an example to get you started:

```
import sys


player_data = {
    "Name": "B Borg",
    "Placement": 1,
    "Won": 5,
    "Played": 10,
    "Percent Won": 0.5
}


def print_format(k, val):
    if k == "Name":
        sys.stdout.write(val.ljust(20, ' '))
    if k == "Placement":
        sys.stdout.write(val.ljust(15, ' '))
    if k == "Won":
        sys.stdout.write(val.center(10, ' '))
    if k == "Played":
        sys.stdout.write(val.center(20, ' '))
    if k == "Percent Won":
        sys.stdout.write(val.center(10, ' '))


# Print the header
[print_format(k, k) for k in player_data.keys()]
print()

# Print the data:
[print_format(k, str(v)) for k, v in player_data.items()]
print()
```

```
(venv) [ttucker@zim bot]$ python justify.py 
Name                Placement         Won           Played       Percent Won
B Borg              1                  5              10            0.5
```